# Making a Meme Generator in Android

Tags: android, android-studio

I want to create a meme generator application for android devices. I want the user to be able to select an image and then be able to put text on top of the image. When the user is done creating the meme I want them to be able to save it to the camera roll. I'm just not sure on where to start with this though.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/training/index.html

Comment: Are you saying you don't know how to program? Well you should start learning a programming language, then start android development and in some years you should be able to make a simple app like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are interested in Developing Android Apps be it any kind of app (for example that Meme Generator) you need to learn android development first and get familiar with it. **Firstly, you should focus on something simple such as a To-Do App if you are yet to make your maiden app**. After you make your first app, you will be able to design your Meme generator as you wish to.

If you are planning to learn android, I would suggest you to follow any of these two MOOC offered by Google. They are available on [Udacity](http://www.udacity.com/).

If you are completely a **Beginner** with **no experience in Object Oriented Programming** you can take this [Beginner Android Course](http://www.udacity.com/course/android-development-for-beginners--ud837). Else if you are **familiar with Object Oriented Programming** you can take this [Course](http://www.udacity.com/course/developing-android-apps--ud853).

Comment: I'm not new to programming. I was just wondering if anyone would have a tutorial or an example on where to start with creating a simple meme generator.

Comment: Well I don't know about any tutorial but if you know android development, then check source code of any of these two open source meme generator android app for reference: http://github.com/jasonycw/MemeCreator/blob/HEAD/README.md and http://f-droid.org/repository/browse/?fdfilter=meme&fdid=com.tmarki.comicmaker